Malformed Entry 1 Issue Not Resolving
I am getting this issue while installing new software on Ubuntu Studio LTS 22.04.3 is the version.
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-packages.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

I have tried everything available on stack exchange and on the web but it is not getting resolved.
Here is my /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-packages.list:
{ deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/openvpn.asc] packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/debian main }


could you please just copy and paste the text contents of the file into your question, instead of screenshot of the editor? After pasting, select the text and click on the text formatting button, {}, please. The thing is, this is hard to read for people with imperfect vision, and impossible to read for people with low and no vision, so they couldn't help you.

Marcus I am getting it correct right away { deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/openvpn.asc] https://packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/debian  main }

@SUNILJOSHI thanks! But it's even more important that you read steeldriver's comment!

It is saying too long making a link for it https://pastebin.com/XH9ez9Gj

@SUNILJOSHI can you confirm that you've read and understood what steeldriver wrote in their comment, and that this is /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-packages.list ???

Marcus I am sending the code from openvpn-packages.list it has this only > { deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/openvpn.asc] packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/debian main }

ah, OK; why are you sending the other thing at all? The error message is very precise that it's that file, not the one you included in your question or your pastebin link.

That's not a legal sources entry, remove the { , } and the space before deb.

deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/openvpn.asc] packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/debian main

this is what you want, now can someone please help me with this?

@SUNILJOSHI I just looked at what you pasted into your comments. If this is not what is in your file, please fix the text in your question. And I don't know what you mean with "help me with this"; I'm trying to do exactly that. Your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-packages.list very clearly is what is broken, and that's what was broken about what you said the file contained.

@MarcusMüller the braces are likely just the OP's misinterpretation of markdown code formatting - the error mentions "component" and we can see that there is a missing distribution name (should be something like jammy main rather than just main I think?)
